# How to change the proxy of the WebBrowser?

Tags: .net, vb.net, proxy

By saying webbrowser, i mean an object created in VB, not like chrome or IE. How can i change the proxy the browser uses to browse pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solutions of your question in C# in the internet, so this is the VB version I can suggest. Just make sure you import System.Runtime.InteropServices.

```
<Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("wininet.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
         Private Shared Function InternetSetOption(ByVal hInternet As IntPtr, ByVal dwOption As Integer, ByVal lpBuffer As IntPtr, ByVal lpdwBufferLength As Integer) As Boolean
                End Function

                Public Structure Struct_INTERNET_PROXY_INFO
                        Public dwAccessType As Integer
                        Public proxy As IntPtr
                        Public proxyBypass As IntPtr
                End Structure

                Private Sub RefreshIESettings(ByVal strProxy As String)
                        Const INTERNET_OPTION_PROXY As Integer = 38
                        Const INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PROXY As Integer = 3

                        Dim struct_IPI As Struct_INTERNET_PROXY_INFO

                        ' Filling in structure
                        struct_IPI.dwAccessType = INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PROXY
                        struct_IPI.proxy = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi(strProxy)
                        struct_IPI.proxyBypass = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi("local")

                        ' Allocating memory
                        Dim intptrStruct As IntPtr = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(Marshal.SizeOf(struct_IPI))

                        ' Converting structure to IntPtr
                        Marshal.StructureToPtr(struct_IPI, intptrStruct, True)

                        Dim iReturn As Boolean = InternetSetOption(IntPtr.Zero, INTERNET_OPTION_PROXY, intptrStruct, System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(struct_IPI))
     End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/wininet/InternetSetOption.html?diff=y) look promising.  http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/wininet/InternetSetOption.html?diff=y